# Python - search for file types and then grep inside them

Tags: python

I'm working on a project with a lot of subdirectories and a lot of file types,
(.v, .c , .sv, .o etc)

I would like to have a Python script that gets as input a
pattern and a file type extension,
and then searches for this pattern recursively for the given file type.

Today i only know how to do something similar in shell using
"find . -name '*.v*' | xargs fgrep !:1"

Can some one help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck on? Have a look at `os.walk` -- it should be easy to find examples and tutorials of pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: I would nominate to close as too broad but if you can edit your question to show us what you already know and which parts you still need help with, it should be fine.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to reproduce `ack`. There might be good reasons to do so (e.g., you really need to reject perl extensions to regexp that Python doesn't handle), but you should still look at it to understand its design choices and decide whether to do things the same or differently instead of reinventing the wheel in a cave.

Comment: Also, what's wrong with wrapping that shell one-liner in a shell function or script? Does it do something wrong, or not do something that you need at all?

Comment: Agree, I think wrapping `ack` would be a better way to go (beyondgrep.com)

Comment: @bakkal thanks for providing the link; I couldn't remember it off-hand, and searching is less fun on a phone than the desktop. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on implementing it in Python and not some simpler wrapper, there's `glob` that can do the `*` expansion to get all files of a given extension e.g.

> The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern
>   according to the rules used by the Unix shell. No tilde expansion is
>   done, but *, ?, and character ranges expressed with [] will be
>   correctly matched.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

From there you can check if the returned files contain the pattern you want